# Intercept full calendar view change action to make an api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm developing a custom calendar using [Full calendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) as base in ReactJS.

Problem statement:

1. I need to do an api call for fetching events when user clicks on Header buttons to change the view of calendar (day, week, month).

Current state:

1. I'm making use of dayGridPlugin and timeGridPlugin,
2. The events are stored in reducer state and passed to calendar.

What I've tried:

callback method viewSkeletonRender to trigger api call and fetch events. These event values are stored to reducer. This results in the infinite api calls since event render method is being called.

I'm trying to find out if there is any callback event on which i can trigger an api call.

Comment: "I need to do an api call for fetching events when user clicks on Header buttons to change the view of calendar "...why? I can't think of a good reason to need to do that. If you implemented a dynamic event feed (e.g. using the [JSON feed](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) or [function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) techniques then fullCalendar will fetch new events from your data source automatically whenever it needs to.

Comment: @ADyson You are correct. However I need new api call because i'm fetching data as i need. So in case if i'm on day view my api call takes only selected date as input param, and for week and month it takes start date and end date.

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work with a dynamic event feed, as well. In the case of the JSON feed technique, fullCalendar will automatically append the correct start and end dates to the request as query parameters (see the documentation link I gave you, if you haven't already). And it will automatically make a new request to the server (with correct dates) whenever it does not already have any data present for the date range which the changed view needs. (For the function technique, you are supplied the start/end dates in the callback so you can append them to your custom request).

Comment: (And this will actually be slightly more efficient than your proposal because sometimes the data will already be present, and a new API request will not be needed. e.g. if the user is viewing January in the month view, and they change to "day" view looking at 6th January, then data for 6th Jan will already have been downloaded when the month view was loaded, so there is no need for a new request. Same thing if the user moves to Feb, and then moves back to January, it will not ask to download January's data again (although you can override this behaviour if you wish)).

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for such brief explanation. So up to what i understood, the correct approach is to have one single API call which consumes dates and produces same response for all views. However i've different APIs for different views. Kindly let me know if this approach is wrong.

Comment: "the correct approach is to have one single API call which consumes dates and produces same response for all views"...yes, that is the recommended and easiest approach. I can't see any reason why you would need different APIs for each view - you are returning the same kind of data in each case, and accepting the same kind of inputs, so it sounds just like duplication.

Comment: There are reasons for this. I show a completely different set of events in a month view (aggregated data per day) than I do on any other view (discrete appt. data). So the ability to add a handler onViewChange would be incredibly helpful to allow me to flip the datasource and keep one component.